# Can I set an arbitrary value for a IP packet's total length?

Tags: sockets, networking, network-programming

When I use raw socket to forge a IP packet, it seems that I can set an arbitrary value for its total length without regarding the true size of IP packet.

However, when I use Wireshark to catch the packet, I found the total length has been corrected to be the true size. This really confused me.

Can somebody explain this issue? I will be very grateful for your help.

Thanks.

Comment: It might have been overwritten by the OS or the network interface driver. Where are you capturing it?

Comment: I capture it on eth0 which is the source device I send the packet. Diego Pino has pointed out that this issue is caused by `sendto` function, the total length I set was overwritten by it. Thank you so much for helping me figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sending a packet larger than its actual size, the additional data in the payload is a chunk of zeroes. That's what in theory you should see on a captured packet of this kind when inspecting it with Wireshark (or tcpdump). For instance:

```
IP 192.168.0.3.17664 > 178.60.128.48.1: tcp 32
        0x0000:  4500 0064 f0d0 4000 4006 56ab c0a8 0003  E..d..@.@.V.....
        0x0010:  b23c 8030 4500 0001 0000 0000 ff06 dbe4  .<.0E...........
        0x0020:  c0a8 0003 b23c 8030 04d2 0050 0000 0000  .....<.0...P....
        0x0030:  0000 0000 5002 16d0 b3c4 0000 4142 4344  ....P.......ABCD
        0x0040:  4546 4748 494a 4b4c 4d4e 4f50 5152 5354  EFGHIJKLMNOPQRST
        0x0050:  5556 5758 595a 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  UVWXYZ..........
        0x0060:  0000 0000                                ....
```

This is TCP packet to google.com (178.60.128.48). The payload is "ABC...XYZ", but the IP's `total_length` has been manually increased. The result is zero padding in the payload until completing the total length of the packet.

That said, my bet is that the problem is in the `sendto` system call. This is the call that actually sends a packet on the socket. But this call also sets the `total_length` of the packet.

```
ssize_t sendto(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags,
               const struct sockaddr *dest_addr, socklen_t addrlen);
```

I suspect you have tweaked the packet's `total_length` field in the IPv4 header, but the `len` parameter on the `sendto` call has not been modified, so the packet's total length is overwritten to its original size when is sent.

That's my suspicion but it's hard to tell without checking the code.

Comment: That‘s exactly where the problem is!! Thank you so much!! I also found that if I set the total length over 1500 bytes (the longest length of an Ethernet frame), the `sendto` function will return an error message `Message too long`.

Comment: @ZhihongDeng I'm glad to hear it's working now. Could you please mark my answer as accepted? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work